# Drawing attention from distance

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, spoken-english

How can I draw my school principal's attention from distance?
Can I say:

> **Hello sir,** I need to speak to you. (*out loud)*

Now, my friend is passing by my house. I want to talk to her just for one or two minutes.

Can I draw her attention by saying:

> **Hey Feifei, listen a minute**

The above two sentences are translations from my native language.

I wonder how a native English speaker would say these?

What are the proper **conjunctions** to be used in these contexts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both of your examples are fine. Where were you thinking of inserting a conjunction?

Comment: It might be considered more polite to attract the principal's attention with "Excuse me, sir".